# Moving whole row between two tables

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have to tables with identical structure, client_data, new_client_data.
Now I want to move whole one row from one table to another. I've found a way to do it, it`s working fine, but I'm wondering if there is more elegant and clean way to do it.

new_client_data / controller:

```
public function actionPromotion($id)
+    {
+        $model = $this->findModel($id);
+        
+        $clientData = new ClientData; 
+        $newClientNumber = $clientData->setNewClientNumber();
+        
+        $clientContacts = new OClientContacts;
+        
+        
+        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
+            if($this->moveToClients(Yii::$app->request->post(), $model->id) & $clientContacts->moveContacts($id)){
+                return $this->redirect(['index']);
+            } else {
+                return $this->render('promprep', [
+                'model' => $model,
+                'newClientNumber' => $newClientNumber,
+            ]);
+            }           
+        } else {
+            return $this->render('promprep', [
+                'model' => $model,
+                'newClientNumber' => $newClientNumber,
+            ]);
+        }
+    }
```

It's basic controller method build from standard actionUpdate.
If user will submit all post data correctly then function is passing all post data to another method in that controller. ( also i`m wondering if shouldn't place in model instead).

```
+    public function moveToClients($post, $id){
+        $ClientData = new ClientData;
+        
+        $ClientData->name = $post['OClientData']['name'];
+        $ClientData->clientNumber = $post['OClientData']['clientNumber'];
+        $ClientData->abr= $post['OClientData']['abr'];
+        $ClientData->adress = $post['OClientData']['adress'];
+        $ClientData->city = $post['OClientData']['city'];
+        $ClientData->postal = $post['OClientData']['postal'];
+        $ClientData->phone = $post['OClientData']['phone'];
+        $ClientData->fax = $post['OClientData']['fax'];
+        $ClientData->email = $post['OClientData']['email'];
+        $ClientData->nip = $post['OClientData']['nip'];
+        $ClientData->krs = $post['OClientData']['krs'];
+        $ClientData->regon = $post['OClientData']['regon'];
+        $ClientData->www = $post['OClientData']['www'];
+        $ClientData->description = $post['OClientData']['description'];
+        $ClientData->isNewRecord = true;
+        $ClientData->id = null;
+        
+        if($ClientData->save()){
+           $this->actionDelete($id);
+            return true;
+        }
+       return false;
+
+    }
```

My question is: "Is there a way to do this in more elegant way?";

Edit. Question: "Should this `moveToClients` method land in the controller?";

Comment: No idea why i get -1 ....

Comment: "_Should this `moveToClients` method land in the controller?_". IMHO this is method devoted entirely into data manipulation and thus, in my understanding of MVC concept, it should by all means be in your model, not in your controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a more elegant way. I believe you should not have two separate tables for the same concept. Instead, you already have a `client_data` table and you should add a new flag, namely, `is_new`. By default, set it to 1 (true). Whenever you need to modify a client to be client, just change the `is_new` flag to 0 (false).

Comment: I need the data in two tables, client demand. They don't want to mix their clients data, and perspective clients data. Like u wouldn't want to mix Your_Own_Projects_Data with Not_Your_Projects_Data, but you would need a way to import the data from second table to first one ( for template reason or something).

Comment: @fsn,  that's not mixing the data. Each record is either for evidently new client or evidently for a client. Your code will stop working whenever a column is changed, removed or added. Also, you will have to maintain the scheme of two separate tables. You might have a client demand to keep these in separate tables, but your question was not about client demands. It was about whether there is a more elegant answer. I have provided one, since it spare you from migrating, it will work even if you add/remove/modify columns and it is clear and optimal.

Comment: thx for you advice i will think about changing table scheme. So if there is no more elegant way to move data from table to another i will accept your answer and close question. Thanks again.

Comment: Alternatively, you can insert with selecting, see here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html, but I believe that is less elegant than using a flag. But, if you need to fit in to client requirements and they remain unchanged, then I recommend using this syntax, you will be able to do batch migrations, which will reduce the number of requests to the database. Your code will still be vulnerable to scheme changes though. I recommend using a flag as the A-plan and using insert select as the B-plan if the client does not change his mind.

Comment: Thank you very much sir :] i will check it :]